# Scripting YSlow and/or PageSpeed

Tags: performance, frontend, yslow

As I'm starting to do some front end engineering at work, I would like to properly quantify the speedup achieved.

I would like to be able to use an average value of, say, 50 page load times measured by  YSlow or Google Page Speed. Obviously, I don't want to hit reload 50 times and write down the value.

Is there a FF plugin for that or will I have to write a Firebug extension myself? Or maybe there is a non-FF, command-line tool that does what I'm planning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently did a talk about this at Google Test Automation Conference in Zurich for this.

Slides for it are [here](http://theautomatedtester.co.uk/presentations/automated_performance_monitor_and_reporting.htm)

And I did a blog post on my company site about it and that can be found [here](http://tech.smartfocusdigital.com/2009/11/performance-monitoring-and-reporting.html)

We were able to use the YSlow Beacon and Selenium together to automate the entire process.

I hope that helps!

Comment: A very thorough solution.I think these tips will come in handy even though I'm not planning to be as comprehensive as this.

Answer (score 1):

Also check out [GTmetrix](http://gtmetrix.com/) which can do PageSpeed and YSlow analysis from a variety of reasons and has a free API you can use to automate this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is required that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you use Grunt in your development workflow, but there is a great package avaible that allows for easy scripting - check it out:

https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-pagespeed

Once you run it, it will output the results as follows:

[image: Grunt pagespeed]

Or, if you prefer to write your own, the Google PageSpeed API is also quite easy to use. Check out this blog post for more information:

http://deanhume.com/home/blogpost/the-google-pagespeed-api-and-mvc-4/86